# To control cobol decimal points

Tags: cobol

I want to write a cobol program when my input is 15.65778 then output should me 15.66
and When my input is 15.65000 then Output should be 15.65.
Here rules is Basically two digits after the decimal point if its zero then output should be same otherwise input should be incremented by 0.1

Iam expecting a solution for this.

Comment: "Iam expecting a solution for this." then you are on the wrong site as you should know from taking the tour. That's not how SO works. "present code what you've tried and what doesn't work"...

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What were the issues you found?

Comment: [COBOL - Picture Clause](https://www.ibmmainframer.com/cobol-tutorial/cobol-picture-clause/)

Comment: @SimonSobisch - Requesting *[a software algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)* is permitted. In those cases, code may not be available for *debugging* until the algorithm is known and implemented.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the standard alignment rules for a receiving item may be used to determine whether to increment the otherwise truncated value.

[See the note at the end for the explanation as to why the code was changed.]

Code:

```
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   01 values-table.
     03 pic 99v9(5) value 15.65000.
     03 pic 99v9(5) value 15.65001.
     03 pic 99v9(5) value 15.65778.
   01 redefines values-table.
     03 values-entry pic 99v9(5) occurs 3 indexed idx.
   01 r pic vpp9(3) value 0.   *> remainder
   01 out-value pic 99.9(5).
   01 out-result pic 99.99.
   procedure division.
       perform varying idx from 1 by 1
       until idx > 3
           move values-entry (idx) to out-value r

           *> r now has the value beyond two decimal places

           *> if that value is greater than zero
           if r > 0

               *> add 0.01 before truncating the result
               compute out-result = values-entry (idx) + 0.01
           else

               *> otherwise truncate the result
               move values-entry (idx) to out-result
           end-if

           display out-value " : " out-result
       end-perform
       goback
       .
```

Output:

```
15.65000 : 15.65
15.65001 : 15.66
15.65778 : 15.66
```

---

**Note:** Previously, the intrinsic function `REM` was used and, while the standard does not specify how to implement `REM`, the implementor may use floating-point. If floating-point is used, the loss of precision during conversion may cause a non-zero value (`xx001`) in the last three digits to become zero. Since the `PICTURE` clause `vpp9(3)` will preserve the exact value, the change was made.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
input pic 99v9(5)
temp pic 99v99
res-r pic 99.99

IF input(5:1) > 4 OR = ZERO 
   COMPUTE temp ROUNDED = input
   move temp to res-r 
ELSE
   COMPUTE temp = input + 0.01
   move temp to res-r 
END-IF
```

input output:

15.65778 --> 15.66

15.65000 --> 15.65

15.65122 --> 15.66

Comment: `pic 99.9(5)` is numeric-edited. `COMPUTE` requires numeric; thus `pic 99v9(5)` should be used.

Comment: that's what i meant, I will edit it, thanks